# failed to connect to server [localhost:27107] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started my mongo service from `cd/Users/ritishkannayagari/Desktop/R/KMIT/FullStack-Coursera/NodeJS/mongodb`

and I started the service with the code `sudo mongod --dbpath=data --bind_ip 127.0.0.1`
my server successfully started.

Then i went to my nodeJs application folder and started my server. it throws the following error :

```
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27107] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107\n' +
    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16) {\n' +
    "  name: 'MongoNetworkError',\n" +
    "  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107',\n" +
    "  stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27107\\n' +\n" +
    "    '    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)'\n" +
    '}]'
}
```

I am trying to connect to the following url of db :

```
mongourl:mongodb://localhost:27107/conFusion
```

I have connected in the following way :

```
const url = config.mongoUrl;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then((db)=>{
  console.log('Connected correctly to server');
},(err)=>{console.log(err)});
```

Comment: can you test your connection with some external app like robomongo ?

Comment: @MohamadrezaRahimianGolkhandani i am able to run mongo on shell and connect mongodb on other project. I am not able to figure out for this project

Comment: Is it possible to get access to your repo ?

Comment: I will push it to git and give you the link.